# Issue with module wrapper function

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to learn node.js, and having an issue with running a code with module wrapper function. Here is the code

logger.js (1)

```
var url = 'http://mylogger.io/log';

function log(message) {
    
    console.log(message);
}

module.exports.log = log;
```

logger.js(2)

```
( function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname)
{
    var url = 'http://mylogger.io/log';

    function log(message) {
        
        console.log(message);
    }

    module.exports.log = log;
})
```

app.js

```
const logger = require('./logger.js')
console.log(logger);
logger.log('Hiya');
```

The logger.js(1) works fine, logger.js(2) gives out following error.

```
TypeError: logger.log is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> ()
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I was expecting to get the same result from both cases

Comment: use 1. then, but you should export it `module.exports = {log}` for it to work

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet which you have attached as `logger.js(2)`,
`function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname)` is irrelevant and does not make sense to the NodeJS Compiler.

The correct way of doing what you expect is the one listed in `logger.js(1)`
If you are exporting multiple functions then,

```
var url = 'http://mylogger.io/log';

function log(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

function log_twice(message) {
    console.log(message);
    console.log(message);
}

module.exports = { log: log, log_twice: log_twice }; //and so on
```

Request to accept the answer if it helps...